# Issue when installing nana in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, nana

I'm trying to use the nana c++ library for my user interface and i followed this tutorial https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Code-Blocks-Linux but when i try to compile this code :

```
    #include <nana/gui.hpp>
    #include <nana/gui/widgets/label.hpp>
    int main()
    {
        using namespace nana;

        form fm;

        label lb{ fm, rectangle{ 10, 10, 100, 100 } };
        lb.caption("Hello, world!");
        fm.show();

        exec();
    }
```

I get this error : g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-nana’
I don't have any idea of what i'm doing wrong. How can i make it works ?

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in the instructions, now fixed

Change `-nana` to `-lnana`